# How to find, count and show card pairs in C, where 2 or 3 of a kind is one pair, and 4 of a kind is two pairs?

Tags: c, playing-cards

I am struggling and have no idea how to determine and show number of pairs where

- 2 or 3 of a kind is one pair and 4 of a kind is two pairs.
- 2 of a kind is 2 cards having the same number, 3 of a kind is 3 cards having the same number, and 4 of a kind is 4 cards having the same number.

How would you find, count and show number of pairs, since the deck of cards has 52 cards?

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

/* handy typedefs */
typedef unsigned char card;
typedef unsigned char pairs;

/* arrays for the names of things */
static char *suits[4] = {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};
static char *values[13]= {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven",
                      "Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
static char *colour[2]= {"Red","Black"};

int compareface(const void * c1, const void * c2);
int comparesuit(const void * c1, const void * c2);
void shuffle(int deck[52]);
pairs findpairs ( card *h ) ; /* finds any pairs in a hand */
int main()
{
 int deck[52];
 pairs numpairs[5], highest;
 int s, c, a, i, j;

 j = 0;
 for(s = 0; s < 4; s++)//for filling a deck of 52 cards
 {
   for(c = 0; c < 13; c++)
   {
   deck[s * 13 + c] = j;
   j++;
   }
 }

for(a = 0; a < 52; a++)
{     
  printf(" %s of", values[ deck[a] % 13 ]);
  printf(" %s, is ", suits[ deck[a] / 13 ]);
  printf("%s\n", colour[ deck[a] / 26 ]);
}

int hands[5][5],h,cd,winner,handssorted[5][5];
int irand;
srand(time(NULL));       /* seed the random number generator */

// shuffle the deck before to get the hands:
shuffle(deck);
j = 0;
for (h=0;h<5;h++)
{
  for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hands[h][i] = deck[j];
    j++;
  }
}
// sort the cards by card value:
for (h=0;h<5;h++)
{
  qsort(hands[h], 5, sizeof(int), compareface);

}
// print the hand:
for (h=0;h<5;h++)
{
  printf("\nHand %d:\n",h+1 );
  for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf(" %s of", values[ hands[h][i] % 13 ]);
    printf(" %s, is ", suits[ hands[h][i] / 13 ]);
    printf("%s\n", colour[ hands[h][i] / 26 ]);
  }
 printf("Number of pairs: \n");
}

// sort the cards by card value then card suit:
for (h=0;h<5;h++)
{
  qsort(hands[h], 5, sizeof(int), comparesuit);
  numpairs[h]= findpairs( handssorted[h] );
}
// print the hand:
  for (h=0;h<5;h++)
  {
   for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = i+1; j < 5; j++) {
     if( (hands[h][i] / 13 > hands[h][j] / 13) && (hands[h][i] % 13 ==  hands[h][j] % 13) ) {
      c = hands[h][i];
      hands[h][i] = hands[h][j];
      hands[h][j] = c;
                                         }
                         }
                       }
              }
       /* determine the winner and print it */
       return 0;
        }

     void shuffle(int deck[52])
     {
      int i,rnd, c;

      for(i=0;i<52;i++)
      {
        /* generate a random number between 0 & 51 */
         rnd=rand() * 52.0 / RAND_MAX;
         c = deck[i];
         deck[i] = deck[rnd];
         deck[rnd] = c;
        }
      }

    int compareface(const void * c1, const void * c2)
    {
    const int cd1 = *(const int*)c1;
    const int cd2 = *(const int*)c2;
    if(cd1 % 13 > cd2 % 13) return 1;
    if(cd1 % 13 == cd2 % 13) return 0;
     return -1;
    }

    int comparesuit(const void * c1, const void * c2)
     {
     const int cd1 = *(const int*)c1;
     const int cd2 = *(const int*)c2;
     if(cd1 / 13 > cd2 / 13) return 1;
     if(cd1 / 13 == cd2 / 13) return 0;
     return -1;
     }

      pairs findpairs ( card *h )
      {
       pairs numpairs=0;
       /* find the pairs here */
       return numpairs;
        }
```

Comment: What does 52 cards have to do with counting pairs? Just count the number of cards that are the same and divide it by 2. 2 and 3 cards gives 1 and four gives 2; just what you wanted.

Comment: Writing a "naive" poker hand evaluator like this, you're on the right track, but a couple of notes: sort the hand first, it will speed up later tests; check for hand types top-down: i.e., straight flush, quads, full house...no pair, rather than bottom up, because that will allow simple early returns. Cards as simple integers is good, but since you've ordered them A,2,3,,,K,A,2,,,,K, you can see that you need lots of %13s. Better to order them 2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,...A,A,A,A, then you only need fast bit masking, and you can compare ranks without even separating them.

Comment: when formatting code, never use tabs for horizontal spacing because every wordprocessor and editor has the tab widths/tab stops set differently.  Suggest using 4 spaces for indenting.   I.E. indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: Can someone give code on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Once the cards are sorted, you can find the pairs just by comparing the consecutive cards. Before that there is another problem in your code, when you are sorting you are sorting it in hands[h] and for findpairs()  you are giving handssorted array. so first copy the values to handssorted and sort them.

After that you just compare the consecutive values in findpairs call. Once you found the pairs increment the pointer to 3rd card.

```
 pairs findpairs ( card *h )
  {
   pairs numpairs=0;
   int card1, card2;
   /* find the pairs here */
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
       /* Compare the card values here */
        card1 = h[i];
        card2 = h[i++]; /*extract values according to your encoding scheme*/
       if(card1 == card2){
          numpairs++;
          i++; // skip the next card to avoid counting 3 of a kind, since it is just a pair 
     }

   return numpairs;
    }
```